# Sum of same objects with Array.reduce in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reduce

I have an array like this:

```
const inputArray = [
  {
    userId: 1,
    sum: 30,
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    sum: 20,
  },
  {
    userId: 2,
    sum: 50,
  },
  {
    userId: 2,
    sum: 80,
  },
];
```

Then I wrote a function that sums the values ​​by key and got the following result:

```
const output = [
  {
    userId: 1,
    sum: 50,
  },
  50,
  {
    userId: 2,
    sum: 130,
  },
  130,
];
```

How can this error be corrected? Function code below:

```
const output = inputArray.reduce((accumulator, currentItem) => {
  const index = accumulator.findIndex((item) => item.userId === currentItem.userId);

  if (index < 0) {
    return [...accumulator, currentItem];
  } else {
    return [...accumulator, (accumulator[index].sum += currentItem.sum)];
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @VLAZ I think he just want the same array with the sum property incremented

Comment: @Nick and I think it would be good to include all relevant information in the question itself.

Comment: Write that so...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, instead of `finding index` as it can be costly iterating array again and again, you can simply make an object with `userId` as key and `sum` as value.

After that, u can do `Object.entries(inputObj)` to make and array of object out of this.

```js
var inputArray = [{ userId: 1,sum: 30},{userId: 1,sum: 20},{userId: 2,sum: 50},{userId: 2,sum: 80}];

var outputObj = inputArray.reduce((finalObj, curObj) => {
  if (!finalObj[curObj.userId]) finalObj[curObj.userId] = curObj.sum  //<--- adding new user if do not exist in the object
  else finalObj[curObj.userId] += curObj.sum; // <---- if already present, the add the sum
  return finalObj;
}, {})

var output = Object.entries(outputObj).map((obj) => ({
  userId: obj[0], //<--- key of object as userId
  sum: obj[1]  //<--- value of object as sum
}));

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
const inputArray = [
  {
    userId: 1,
    sum: 30,
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    sum: 20,
  },
  {
    userId: 2,
    sum: 50,
  },
  {
    userId: 2,
    sum: 80,
  },
];

const output = inputArray.reduce((accumulator, currentItem) => {
  const matchedItem = accumulator.find((item) => item.userId === currentItem.userId);

  if (!matchedItem) {
    return [...accumulator, currentItem];
  } else {
    matchedItem.sum += currentItem.sum
    return accumulator
  }
}, []);

console.log(output)
```

you were appending a new item to accumulator even when the item already existed, you just needed to mutate it.  Also, since you dealing with an array of objects, you can use `find` as it will return a reference to the matched object itself, letting you update the object directly, rather than having to use `findIndex` then use the index to find it in the array again

Comment: Yes, it works, but this way mutates the original array

Comment: so whats the problem with mutating the array?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
const inputArray = [
  {
    userId: 1,
    sum: 30,
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    sum: 20,
  },
  {
    userId: 2,
    sum: 50,
  },
  {
    userId: 2,
    sum: 80,
  },
];

const res = Array.from(inputArray.reduce((m, {userId, sum}) => m.set(userId, (m.get(userId) || 0) + sum), new Map), ([userId, sum]) => ({userId, sum}));
```